# ESLint: Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in '../../.eslintrc.js Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'

Tags: next.js, eslint, prettier, eslintrc

**What actually happened?**

```
error - ESLint: Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in '../../.eslintrc.js » ./config/base.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier' Require stack: - /../projects/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/__placeholder__.js
```

> I was just trying to upgrade packages of my NextJS project, previously
> It was working fine with versions mentioned below:

- NodeJS : `16.20.0`
- NextJS : `10.0.6`
- ReactJS : `17.0.1`
- ESLint : `7.19.0`
- eslint-config-prettier : `7.2.0`
- eslint-plugin-prettier : `3.3.1`

And upgraded to following versions:

- NodeJS : `18.15.0`
- NextJS : `13.3.0`
- ReactJS : `18.2.0`
- ESLint : `8.38.0`
- eslint-config-prettier : `8.8.0`
- eslint-plugin-prettier : `4.2.1`

But now it is throwing error at the time of building project.

```
error - ESLint: Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in '../../.eslintrc.js » ./config/base.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier' Require stack: - /../projects/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/__placeholder__.js
```

Please let me know that how can I overcome this issue.

**version of `eslint`:**
8.38.0

**version of `prettier`:**
2.8.7

**version of `eslint-plugin-prettier`:**
4.2.1

**config files that I'm using :**
.eslintrc

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended'
  ],
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 9,
    ecmaFeatures: {
      experimentalObjectRestSpread: true,
      impliedStrict: true,
      classes: true
    }
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    jest: true
  },
  settings: {
    'import/internal-regex': '^~'
  },
  rules: {
    strict: 0,
    'prettier/prettier': 'error',
    'no-console': 'error',
    'no-debugger': 'error',
    'no-alert': 'error',
    'no-await-in-loop': 0,
    'no-return-assign': ['error', 'except-parens'],
    'no-restricted-syntax': [
      2,
      'ForInStatement',
      'LabeledStatement',
      'WithStatement'
    ],
    'no-unused-vars': [
      'error',
      {
        args: 'all',
        ignoreRestSiblings: true,
        argsIgnorePattern: '^_',
        caughtErrors: 'all'
      }
    ],
    'prefer-const': [
      'error',
      {
        destructuring: 'all'
      }
    ],
    'arrow-body-style': [2, 'as-needed'],
    'no-unused-expressions': [
      2,
      {
        allowTaggedTemplates: true
      }
    ],
    'no-param-reassign': [
      2,
      {
        props: false
      }
    ],
    'import/order': [
      'error',
      {
        groups: [
          'builtin',
          'external',
          'internal',
          'unknown',
          'index',
          ['sibling', 'parent'],
          'object'
        ],
        'newlines-between': 'always',
        pathGroups: [
          {
            pattern: '~/**',
            group: 'internal'
          }
        ],
        pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes: ['builtin', 'external']
      }
    ],
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    import: 0,
    'func-names': 0,
    'space-before-function-paren': 0,
    'comma-dangle': 0,
    'max-len': 0,
    'import/extensions': 0,
    'import/no-named-as-default': 0,
    'no-underscore-dangle': 0,
    'consistent-return': 0,
    'react/display-name': 1,
    'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'error',
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn',
    'react/no-array-index-key': 0,
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 0,
    'react/prefer-stateless-function': 0,
    'react/forbid-prop-types': 0,
    'react/no-unescaped-entities': 0,
    'react/static-property-placement': [1, 'static public field'],
    'jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions': 0,
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': [
      2,
      {
        html: 'enforce',
        custom: 'ignore',
        explicitSpread: 'ignore'
      }
    ],
    'react/require-default-props': 0,
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [
      1,
      {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
      }
    ],
    radix: 0,
    'no-shadow': [
      2,
      {
        hoist: 'all',
        allow: ['resolve', 'reject', 'done', 'next', 'err', 'error']
      }
    ],
    quotes: [
      2,
      'single',
      {
        avoidEscape: true,
        allowTemplateLiterals: true
      }
    ],
    'jsx-a11y/href-no-hash': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': [
      'warn',
      {
        aspects: ['invalidHref']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: ['react-hooks','prettier']
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to declare prettier in your ESLint config :

You need to specify it in your ESLintrc :

```
 extends: [
    'prettier',
  ],
  plugins: ['prettier'],
```

And then you can put your prettier rules (only if you have some) directly in your eslintrc like that :

```
rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        semi: true,
        /* your rules */
      },
    ],
}
```

[How to use prettier with eslint](https://www.robinwieruch.de/prettier-eslint/)

Hope it works for you !

Comment: Thank you for answer. but it was already there in my ESLintrc.
Still getting that error at the time of building project.

Comment: Have you tried to launch  `npm i prettier`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using yarn workspace. So tried with `yarn add prettier`.

Comment: have you tried to delete your node_modules and relaunch `npm i` instead ?

Comment: Yes, but didn't help.

Comment: What is your yarn version please ?

Comment: yarn version is:`2.4.0`

Comment: You can try to upgrade to yarn 3 and retry installing your modules

Comment:  Thank you for the suggestion, I tried reinstalling with latest yarn `3.5.0` , but still no luck

Comment: Well, I don't know how to help you ... maybe you can try to look at this issue it might help you : [Issue Github](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/issues/396) Good luck finding it !